# How to remove this error -> Json parsing error: Value success at response of type java.lang.String can't be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json

I'm getting JSON parsing error while running my app

Below mentioned the code where I'm facing the error and the json url https://zactra.com/blackboard/teacher/auth/email/check/numankhan2754@gmail.com

```
           MyHttpHandler myhttp = new MyHttpHandler();
           String Newurl = url + "auth/email/check/"+email+"/";

            // call MyServiceCall method from Myhttphandler class

            String jsonstng = myhttp.MyServiceCall(Newurl);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response From URL: " + jsonstng);
            if (jsonstng != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonstng);

                    //getting JSON array node
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("response");

                    // Looping through all data from json
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject loopjsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        myid = loopjsonObject.getString("response");

                        // tmp hash map for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> mydata = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        mydata.put("response", myid);

                        mydatalist.add(mydata);


                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            Toast.makeText(StartMainActivity.this, "JSON parsing error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(StartMainActivity.this, "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        }
```

Response From URL: `{"response":"success"}`

Json parsing error: `Value success at response of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray`

Comment: by not trying to parse a String to a JSONArray. There is no hierarchical connection between the two, no IS-A relation, so you can't parse it.

Comment: The json you are trying to parse does not follow the pattern you have defined, you're expecting the form { "" : [] } but the json has the form { "" : "" }. What you're looking for can be done but you need to decide what to do in the case where the value is a string and not an array, do you want null, an empty arry or an array including the value?

Answer (score 2):

Well

```
'success'
```

is not a json array.
an example of a json array is the following

```
"cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
```

that is why it cannot be parsed.

the upper example 'cars' array has String values. so String Objects.

In your example you have after the jsonArray a for loop for the jsonArray

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)

there you say that you expect JSONObject
so the format that you are waiting is

```
   {"response":[ {"response":"success"},{"response":"success"},{"response":"success"} ]}
```

which i believe is not the one you finally want :P.

You also create a new HashMap<>() inside the loop. (read about HashMap because your implementation does not support the same key usage ex. cannot have a hashmap with two string objects with same key 'response')
do not make only checks for null checks, do also checks if the string is blank.

First, define the correct format of the response from your service, then the correct implementation for you to capture your data and search the web so that the response to be parsed to an object by the use of a library like jackson.

Regards!

Ps if you want to handle this response,
then

```
String jsonstng = "{\"response\":\"success\"}";//your service response
    String responseValue = "fail";
    if (jsonstng != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonstng);
            if (jsonObject.length() > 0 && jsonObject.has("response")) {
                responseValue = jsonObject.getString("response");
            }
        } catch (final JSONException e) {
            //log and handle error
        }
    }
    System.out.println(responseValue);
```

may be enough

Comment: Which is the best way i learn about json with android.because i’m not expert and not much how now about this.

Comment: There are many options for you. Start reading from https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp  to learn for JSON. Then check for JSON to java objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
{"response":"success"} is a JSONObject but you are treating it as JSONArray.
```

JSON array is always wrapped with `[]`
Example : `["a", "b", "c"]` OR something like array of JSONObjects . For example : `[{"key":"value"}, {"key","value"}]` . Many combinations are possible but most importantly it should start with `[]`

Comment: Actually this is my login form information when the email and password which store on server and getting through jason is match with enter email and password then display success